# How to hide certain things on navbar unless user is authorized? (Rails + Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a couple links that I want to hide unless the user is authorized to see it. I created an extra column in my User model that is called super and I want to do something similar to the code below:

```
<% if current_user.super == true  %> 
      <li><%= link_to "Hidden", hidden_path %></li>  
    <% end %>
```

The super is defined as a boolean and already set to true. I'm getting an error saying that they don't recognize "super"

Comment: `super` is a **keyword** in ruby, may be its causing problem for you. Try with different column name.

Comment: Here, `super` is a reserved keyword. You may like to rename it to `admin`. You can check a list of reserved keywords http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words

Comment: Dump the value of current_user.super to your form and see if you're indeed getting the output that you expect.

Comment: @MarsAtomic without the <%if%> line of code, the site runs fine. It's saying that pro is undefined method `pro?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Well, there's your problem then. current_user isn't set. Find out why. It's almost impossible to say what's going on without knowing how you've set up Devise, so I would retrace my steps if I were you. Is your controller missing `before_action :set_user` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super` is a ruby keyword,. With devise you can check as

```
<% if current_user.present?  %> 
  <li><%= link_to "Hidden", hidden_path %></li>  
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% if user_signed_in? %> 
  <li><%= link_to "Hidden", hidden_path %></li>  
<% end %>
```

Devise provides these helper methods,

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Comment: thanks for the help, i know that I can do it with "if user_signed_in?" , but i'm trying to give different permissions to accounts differently. I can't do something like <% unless current.user.super? %>?

Comment: Reserved keywords can't be kept as a column name. Kindly change the user table column name to `is_super` / `admin`.

Comment: I just changed it to pro and it still doesn't work  <% if current_user.pro?  %> 
      <li><%= link_to "Hidden", hidden_path %></li>  
    <% end %>

Comment: Your answer seems to confuse authentication (Devise) with authorization (CanCanCan, Pundit, et. al.).

Comment: As long as the `pro` field in user table stores as boolean and returns the boolean, things should work. `current_user.pro.class` should return either a `TrueClass` or `FalseClass`,.

Comment: @Sasidaran ahh I think it's because I have a before filter before_filter :authenticate_user!